# Change vector's entries values automatically in r

Tags: r, concatenation

I have the following vector `x`:

```
  x = [
    60
    
    60
    
    80
    
    0
    
    0
    
    1
    
    2]
```

I want to rewrite a code in r that can transform "automatically" the above vector `x` to:

```
    x = [
        1960
        
        1960
        
        1980
        
        2000
        
        2000
        
        2001
        
        2002]
```

I wrote the code below, but it is not working.

```
x[x>=60 && x<=80] <- 1900 + x
x[x>=0 && x<=2] <- 2000 + x
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the dput of the data.  The data looks like python `list`

Comment: Change the `&&` to `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. And follow the smart advice of **@AllanCameron**:

```
#Code
x[x>=60 & x<=80] <- 1900 + x[x>=60 & x<=80]
x[x>=0 & x<=2] <- 2000 + x[x>=0 & x<=2]
```

Output:

```
x
[1] 1960 1960 1980 2000 2000 2001 2002
```

And as a reminder, vectors in `R` are of this style:

```
#Data
x <- c(60, 60, 80, 0, 0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `case_when` in a single line

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(x >=60 & x <= 80 ~ 1900 + x, x >= 0 & x <=2 ~ 2000 + x, TRUE ~ x)
```

-output

```
x
#[1] 1960 1960 1980 2000 2000 2001 2002
```

---

Or using `ifelse` in `base R`

```
ifelse(x >=0 & x <= 2, 2000 + x, 1900 + x)
```

#### data

```
x <- c(60, 60, 80, 0, 0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x <- c(60, 60, 80, 0, 0, 1, 2)

library(dplyr)
x <- x + if_else(x>=60,1900,2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
x <- c(60, 60, 80, 0, 0, 1, 2)
x + c(2000, 1900)[(x >= 60 & x <= 80) + 1]

#[1] 1960 1960 1980 2000 2000 2001 2002
```

Or in the opposite way

```
x + c(1900, 2000)[(x >= 0 & x <= 2) + 1]
```